# Lollipop shared element transition for mapView?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-mapview, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a mapView that takes up a small portion of the screen, that when touched opens to a full screen view.

I accomplish this by switching between two fragments.

I'd love to use the new Lollipop animation framework to expand the small mapView seamlessly to the larger mapView (from Fragment1 to Fragment2).

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to get it to work -- and am wondering if anyone has been able to get a mapView to work with the new animation framework.

My code:

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void launchMapFullscreenFragment(Fragment previousFragment, MapView mapView)
{
    // Launch fragment to view Google Maps
    FragmentMapFullScreen fragment = new FragmentMapFullScreen();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        previousFragment.setSharedElementReturnTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
        previousFragment.setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));

        // Create new fragment to add (Fragment B)
        fragment.setSharedElementEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(R.transition.change_image_transform));
        fragment.setEnterTransition(TransitionInflater.from(this).inflateTransition(android.R.transition.explode));

        // Add Fragment B
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                .addToBackStack("transaction")
                .addSharedElement(mapView, "MyTransition");
        ft.commit();
    }
    else
    {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.abc_fade_out);
        ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, FRAGMENT_MAP_FULLSCREEN);
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
}
```

change_image_transform.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <changeTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't explicitly worked with MapView, but the docs show it as a FrameLayout, which should work. You haven't shown your two layout files. ChangeTransform will animate the scale, translation, and rotation in the target Fragment from the values in the source Fragment. If you don't have a scaleX or scaleY set in your source or target Fragment's MapViews, then ChangeTransform won't do anything special.

If the MapViews are changing size (not just scale), you should add a ChangeBounds Transition to it along with the ChangeTransform.

Another problem may be the parameter you pass into addSharedElement. The name "MyTransition" should match the transitionName of the MapView in your target Fragment (FragmentMapFullScreen). So your MapView should be something like this:

```
<MapView android:transitionName="MyTransition" ... />
```

If you suspect that the MapView is a culprit (and it may be, depending on its implementation), you can try a TextView to see if that transitions as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it with MapView inside another activity not with MapFragment. Just postpone transition and resume it on the end of onMapReady callback.